# how to persist search term in the field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using ruby on rails and have a search form like:

```
 <%= form_tag '/findBlood' do %>
        Blood Group   <%= text_field_tag "bloodGroup" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
    <% end %>
```

This works as expected however, on submit the bloodGroup field clears and as a result probably pagination breaks. how to retain this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you

```
<%= text_field_tag 'bloodGroup', params[:bloodGroup] %>
```

See docs for [text_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag)

---

The reason a symbol works and the string (other answer) doesn't work:

```
foo = {hello: 'world'}
puts foo[:hello];        # => 'world'
puts foo['hello']        # => nil
puts foo['hello'.to_sym] # => 'world'
```

You can easily convert between strings and symbols in Ruby, but they are not equal.

Comment: This is the exact same answer as the person below.

Comment: @areke, see the added explanation in my answer

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault for not seeing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= text_field_tag "bloodGroup", params["bloodGroup"] %>
```